# AmbiguousMatchException between base controller and derived controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a simple .NET Core project, this is base controller:

```
using MyProject.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ControllerBase : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller
    {   

        [HttpGet]
        public List<Product> xxxx()
        {
            return products.ToList(); 
        }
        ...
```

and this is derived controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MyProject.Models;

namespace MyProject.Controllers
{

    public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public List<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return products.ToList();
        }
    ...
```

Yet I keep getting error

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: 

MyProject.Controllers.ControllerBase.xxxx 
MyProject.Controllers.ProductsController.xxxx
```

I tried:

- Using inheritance from ControllerBase class (seemed mightier) for base controller:
  `public class ControllerBase : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase`
- With and without [ApiController] attribute

It puzzles me why I get this error, when "xxxx" method is just in the base controller, not in derived also. Furthermore, what would happen if **I actually do have** methods with the same name in both controllers (I expect that to happen)

EDIT:
I need to preserve `api/[action]` nomenclature because my client app makes the calls in that way to the existing Web API, I cannot change it to `api/[controller]/[action]` or something else. I'm rewriting the current Web API to .NET core.

So the client app should be able to access both `api/xxxx` and `api/GetAllProducts` without using controller name in the endpoint.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating BaseController for ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19566521/creating-basecontroller-for-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to have a list of Products in derived controllers or do you want to have the same action for every derived controller?

Answer (score 0):

If you further inspect the exception message, the actual problem is inheritance in combination with your route-template:

```
Conflicting method/path combination "GET api/xxxx" for actions - 
WebApplication1.Controllers.ControllerBase.xxxx (WebApplication1),
WebApplication1.Controllers.ProductsController.xxxx (WebApplication1)
```

Since you inherit from `ControllerBase`, `ProductsController` has the Action `xxxx` as well. Your template specifies the Action as the second route-paramter, so this cannot work.

If you want to achieve exactly this behaviuor, you have to add the controller to the route-template: `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]`

But .. than you will have a route like `api/controllerBase/xxx` - if your base is actually a meaningful resource, this could be a solution but it depends on what you´re actually trying to achieve here.

Take a look at the [docs-example](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio). This is a good design guideline on how to build a rest-api. If you're trying to build a common base for your Products (e.g. to pre-fetch entities for every action) you should consider another approach. Take a look at [Action-Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0) or override `OnActionExecutionAsync` in your BaseController:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected List<Product> Products = new();

    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, 
                ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        Products = GetProductsFromSomewhere();
        await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
    }
}
```

Than you can access `Products`-property in every controller that inherits from baseController (just like you did in `GetAllProducts()`).

And one more note: If you have multiple actions with the same name, consider to remove `[action]` from your template and add the route-param to the action-attribute: `[HttpGet("myOtherAction")]`.

Comment: The thing is, I already have Web API but it's .net framework, not .net core. I have an app that calls all the methods from all controllers without mentioning controllers in the route, so in my example it would be `api/xxxx` or `api/GetAllProducts` - not `api/Products/GetAllProducts`. I cannot change hundreds of calls in the client app to change the endpoints there, I need to preserve this nomenclature: `api/[action]`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, there were 2 ways:

1. base controller should be defined as `public abstract class ControllerBase...`.
   It works fine, although I don't understand why to be honest, because if I understand abstract classes well, then the derived class should have all the methods that the base class has, but it's quite contrary: If I put the method with the same name in the derived controller (ProductsController), I have the same error as before. But this works.
2. I created just empty `ControllerBase` for inheritance, and also separate class for its actions, so the code looks like the following. This is a solution that I selected because I understand it.

`

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[action]")]
public class ControllerBase : Controller
{
}

[ApiController]
[Route("api/[action]")]
public class ControllerBaseActions : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    public List<Product> xxxx()
    {
        return products.ToList();
    }
...
```